# Sequelize [Op.and] not working with M:N association

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two models

Units and Filters which are related with M:N association through unit_filter table

```
 this.belongsToMany(Unit, {
        through: "unit_filter",
        as: "units",
      });

  this.belongsToMany(Filter, {
        through: 'unit_filter',
        as: 'filters',
      });
```

The goal is to fetch units which have more than 1 filter associated with and condition.

```
let result = await Unit.findAll({
          include: [
            {
              model: Filter,
              where: {
                id: {
                  [Op.and] : [2,252,4,80]
                }
              },
              as: 'filters',
            },
          ],
        });
```

The above is only working if there is only one id in the array which does not make any sense.

Seqeulize documenation states

```
  Post.findAll({
      where: {
       [Op.and]: [{ a: 5 }, { b: 6 }],            // (a = 5) AND (b = 6)
      }
    })
```

So the code I have should work theoritically. I also tried with

```
where: {
   [Op.and] : [{id:2},{id:252},{id:4},{id:80}]
}
```

which results in getting all the items from the db. It does not even care about the where condition in this case.

Would be of great help if any one points me in right direction.

Comment: You need to use `Sequelize.literal` with a subquery in `where` option in order to filter units that have more than 1 filter because simply indicating several ids of filters you will get units that have one of indicated filters (from 1 to N).

Comment: Try using `[Op.in]: [2,252,4,80]` instead of `[Op.and]`.  This will fetch any filters with these ids.  But I don't quite understand what exactly is your goal: "The goal is to fetch units which have more than 1 filter associated with and condition.".   Any samples would help.

Comment: @Emma  Op.in will fetch units with those IDs . I want a unit which has all those ids . If unit1 has filters 2 and unit2 has filters 2,252,4,80 Op.in will fetch both the units . .  My requirement is to get unit2 only, as only that fulfils my condition, which is to get units which has all the ids which are in the array .

Comment: @Anatoly, Could you give me a Code example. Would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Sequelize.literal` with a subquery in `where` option in order to filter units that have more than 1 filter because simply indicating several ids of filters you will get units that have one of indicated filters (from 1 to N).

```js
let result = await Unit.findAll({
   where: Sequelize.where(
           Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM unit_filter as uf WHERE uf.unit_id=unit.id AND uf.filter_id in ($filter_ids))'),
           Op.gt,
           '1'),
   bind: {
     filter_ids: [2,252,4,80]
   }
});
```

Comment: I am getting a missing FROM-clause entry for table.
I solved it with raw query 

await sequelize.query(
          `select "UnitId" from unit_filter where unit_filter."FilterId" in (SELECT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY($filterIds, ','))::int) group by "UnitId" having count(distinct unit_filter."FilterId" ) = $filterIdslength`,
          {
            bind: {
              filterIds: filterids, filterIdslength: filterids.length
}}.

Then passing the result to unit.findAll . Can be converted to single statement. Thank you for your help.